# Using AnimationManager from Android-pdfview

Tags: java, android, android-pdf-api

I am using [Android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview) library to display pdfs within my application.

```
pdfView.fromFile(new File("/path/to/file")).defaultPage(1).enableSwipe(true).onPageChange(this).load();
```

How to use [AnimationManager](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/blob/master/android-pdfview/src/main/java/com/joanzapata/pdfview/AnimationManager.java) from [Android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview) library ?

For example, I want to show each page for 10 seconds, and move to next page automatically without user interaction. Once last page is reached, loop again.

Comment: Use AsyncTask/Handlers.